# JavaScript: Reset countdown timer + turn off webcam stream automatically once it reaches zero?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, webcam, countdown

I am working on a project where I want the user's live webcam feed to turn off after a 15 second countdown has hit zero. The webcam turns on fine with a button click, but I can't seem to figure out how to get my 15 second countdown timer to reset automatically once it hits zero and the video to turn off.

Everything I have seen online so far relies on either a reset button or page refresh to set the timer back to its original value. Is there any way to completely automate it so that nothing needs to be clicked or refreshed? Once zero is reached, the timer should reset to 15 and the video shuts off.

I am really struggling here.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h3 id="timer">15</h3>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<button id="startBtn" onclick="goLive()">Go Live</button>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<video id="videoCam"></video>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var countdown;
var time;

function trigger() {
  if(time > 0) {
     time--;
       document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
      if(time > 0) {
           countdown = setTimeout('trigger()', 1000);
      }
  }
}

function reset() {
   clearTimeout(countdown);
}

function goLive(){

time = 16;
reset();
trigger();
    
         let All_mediaDevices=navigator.mediaDevices
         if (!All_mediaDevices || !All_mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            console.log("getUserMedia() not supported.");
            return;
         }
         All_mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: true
         })
         .then(function(vidStream) {
            var video = document.getElementById('videoCam');
            if ("srcObject" in video) {
               video.srcObject = vidStream;
            } else {
               video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vidStream);
            }
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
               video.play();
            };
         })
         .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
         });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for setTimeout
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp